# roots of piecewise cubic hermite interpolator with python

Tags: python, matlab, scipy, interpolation

I would like to do some piecewise cubic hermite interpolation and get the **roots** of the polynomials. (I used to do this in matlab but would now like to implement this in python 3.4).
I tried to use the scipy PchipInterpolator. Interpolation is OK but when I tried to retrieve the roots I got this error...
I now am stuck here and could'nt find any workaround. Here is a simple code reproducing what I do and the exact error message...

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import interpolate, __version__
import numpy as np

print('numpy : ' + np.__version__)
print('scipy :' + __version__)

x = np.arange(10)
y = [1., 1., 3., 2., 1., 1., 1.5, 2., 8., 1.]
f = interpolate.PchipInterpolator(x, y, axis=0, extrapolate=None)
print(f.roots()) # this produces an error !

xnew = np.arange(0, 9, 0.1)
ynew = f(xnew)   # use interpolation function returned by `PchipInterpolator`
plt.plot(x, y, 'o', xnew, ynew, '-')
plt.show()
```

The error message :

```
numpy : 1.10.1
scipy :0.17.1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 11, in <module>
    print(f.roots()) # this produces an error !
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/scipy/interpolate/_monotone.py", line 105, in roots
    return (PPoly.from_bernstein_basis(self._bpoly)).roots()
AttributeError: 'PchipInterpolator' object has no attribute '_bpoly'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

However scipy docs say : "roots()   Return the roots of the interpolated function."

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bug in scipy.

(Please report it on https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues)

As a workaround, you can convert to the power basis manually:

```
In [1]: from scipy.interpolate import pchip

In [2]: import numpy as np

In [3]: x = np.arange(10)

In [4]: y = [1., 1., 3., 2., 1., 1., 1.5, 2., 8., 1.]

In [5]: s = pchip(x, y)

In [6]: from scipy.interpolate import PPoly

In [7]: pp = PPoly.from
PPoly.from_bernstein_basis  PPoly.from_spline

In [7]: pp = PPoly.from_bernstein_basis(s)

In [8]: pp.roots()
Out[8]: array([  9.07179677,  22.92820323])
```

EDIT: and if do use this workaround and you have non-default `axis`, best check that the axis is handled when converting. If it's not, please report it too.