# python pchip interpolate missing attribute

Tags: python, scipy, interpolation

I a trying to find the roots of a curve using scipy's pchipInterpolate.roots() and I am getting an attribute error. The code works on my other computer so I'm not entirely sure what the problem is... Here is the error:

```
return (PPoly.from_bernstein_basis(self._bpoly)).roots() 
AttributeError: 'PchipInterpolator' object has no attribute '_bpoly'
```

here is a link to the source code that is causing the problem [link](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v0.17.0/scipy/interpolate/_monotone.py#L101-L105). Any ideas?

Comment: Any differences in the scipy and Python versions on the machines you're using?

Comment: @Evert cant check at the moment but they should be the same, just uninstalled and reinstalled on both computers within the last week. Did find [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38234448/roots-of-piecewise-cubic-hermite-interpolator-with-python) answer but it must be fixed by now if it works on my other computer...

Comment: `_bpoly` has been renamed to `_b` from version 0.15 to 0.16, judging from the source code (as this is a private variable, it wasn't made backwards compatible). So the failing machine likely runs a more recent version of scipy.

Comment: Looking at your linked answer, that means that the aforementioned change has escaped detection. So if in contrast, the working machine runs the most recent scipy version, you'll simply want to upgrade scipy on the failing machine.

Comment: Although my previous two comment really depend on whether *you*'re the one calling `self._bpoly` (seems unlikely, with the `self` usage), or that the scipy code itself calls `_bpoly`. If the former, change to using `._b`, and upgrade scipy on the working machine. If the latter, upgrade on the failing machine.

Comment: @Evert I'm not calling _bpoly. I just updated the scipy package to 0.18 ... still not working though, getting the same error. This is very strange.

Comment: Can you add the full traceback; there must be more than just those two lines.

Comment: [This pull request](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/pull/6462) on the SciPy GitHub page has the 18.1 tag. So it unfortunately didn't make it into 18.0.

Comment: If you're willing, you could try to install the current SciPy master. Assuming you're using `pip`, that would be `pip install --upgrade git+https://github.com/scipy/scipy.git`. Though that still doesn't explain why things work on your other machine. You could have a peek at the relevant SciPy installed code on that machine, to see if that matches 18.0, 17.0, earlier, or current master.

Comment: @Evert ok so 0.18.1 does fix the problem. BUT here is the really strange thing. I checked the computer that the code originally worked on and it is using 0.17.1 where the line of code in the roots function still reads `self._bpoly` and not `self`and it works perfectly. Anyway I think I'll just update both machines to 0.18.1 to avoid further problems. Thanks for the help!